# How are solar panels at equator placed?

Tags: solar-energy

Are solar panels placed horizontally at the equators since the solar altitude (solar window) changes direction from north to south?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, yes, but any shading caused by buildings / other obstructions may make one direction preferential.

You can find sites that will do simulations online...